# Azure appservice adding webjob failing

Tags: azure, service, webjob, ase

Every time i am trying to add a webjob under app service i am getting failure message. Previously it was working, from last 2 weeks i am not able to create a webjob.

[image]

Tried adding webjobs 50+ times

When i am trying to add manually through kudu its uploaded but under webjobs nothing created.

Error message Failed to add "Webjob name".

trying to create webjobs in azure portal>appservice>webjob>create new

[image: Zip contains .exe, .pdb, .dll files]

Comment: Much more information will be required for someone to offer a suggestion. Are you using some version of Net Framework, Net core, Python, Java, etc? Screenshots of the error message? How are you deploying? Where are you deploying to exactly? The more information you can provide, the higher the probability that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: What your file upload is ?

Comment: its a publish.zip file. basically i created a .netcore console app and after publish i just zipped the folder and trying to upload as a web job in azure portal. it was working good before but from last 2/3 weeks i am getting failure message always.

Comment: Hi, Can you show the content of your zip file? It will helps solve the problem.

Comment: added a screenshot of zip contains, thanks

Comment: What is your .net core console app name? use a cmd to run it.

Comment: use cmd to run the .dll file. If your app is .NET Core, only publish and zipped is not enough.

Comment: I will answer this question, you can have a try.

Comment: Have your problem be solved with you? what happened with that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this problem occurs because you don't have a specific file that webjob need.

I create a .net core console app, after publish it, I zipped the folder and want to upload it as a webjob.

[image]

[image]

failed, as yours.

[image]

The solution is add a .cmd file in the folder and zip it with other files.

***run.cmd:***

```
@echo off

dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll
```

Now, these are the whole content that will inside the zip:

[image]

zip these files and upload.

[image]

Finally, works.

[image]

I hope this solution can help you. Please let me know if your problem is different from this.

Comment: My console name is 'ConsoleApp1', I don't know the name of yours. If your problem is simmlar to mine, just use .cmd file to run the .dll file of your console app.

Comment: thanks for the solution, i will try this out.. but i have .exe inside the zip, exe does not work?

Comment: @RatikantaParida .exe works on my side. You can have a try of this solution. If it still doesn't work, please let me know. maybe other problem.

Comment: @RatikantaParida Can your .exe file  run in your local environment

Comment: i found another way to upload webjobs through visual studio webjob project, this way we can directly publish a webjob from VS

Comment: @RatikantaParida Yes! you should have used this method. I was confused at that time why you posted to the profile and uploaded it to the webapp. In fact, this can be published directly through VS. I am sorry that I have not solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in publish profile. You need to configure your publish artifact according to the App Service configuration.

[image: Publish configuration]

[image: App Service Configurations]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the executable file (exe, bat, cmd, etc.) needed to be in the root of the zip for it to work.